How to return a response object from a RawDecorator in Cask
I am trying to validate a devKey using a RawDecorator in Cask HTTP framework, but I am not sure I understand how to return an error response when the devKey is invalid. Here is what I am trying:
class AuthenticatedDevKey extends RawDecorator
{
    override def wrapFunction(ctx: Request, delegate: Delegate) =
    {
        // Get the devKey from header
        val devKey = ctx.headers.getOrElse("devKey", "").toString
        // Check if this is a valid devKey
        if(devKey != "" && MicroServiceManager.isExistingDevKey(devKey))
            delegate(Map("devKey" -> devKey))
        else
            cask.Response("Invalid DevKey", statusCode = StatusCodes.UNAUTHORIZED)

    }
}

This gives me a type mismatch error. The documentation (https://com-lihaoyi.github.io/cask/index.html#extending-endpoints-with-decorators) says that I can return a response, but I have not seen any such example.
How do I return a Response with error statuscode?

Could you edit your post and share a minimal reproducible example?

Ran into this myself just recently, as someone new to both Cask and Scala.
In an Endpoint you can directly return a Response, but in a Decorator you need to wrap the Response in a Result, because a Decorator must return a Result.
In your case, this should do the trick:
cask.router.Result.Success(cask.Response("Invalid DevKey", statusCode = StatusCodes.UNAUTHORIZED))

Note that Result.Success means that your code executed successfully, not that the request was successful. Here it means that you've "successfully" determined that the request is unauthorized.
It's possible there's a better answer, but this is working for me. I also opened a PR to update the Cask docs with an example, so if there is a better way to do it then hopefully the maintainer will correct me there.

I found this out myself, from the code repo (https://github.com/com-lihaoyi/cask/blob/master/cask/src/cask/endpoints/FormEndpoint.scala). Was planning to put this up as a response. Thanks for posting this.

not sure what is the full error message you got, but based on the example provided I would think you need to return a Left[cask.Response] to avoid further processing as it is detailed in the link you shared for Cask - Extending Endpoints with Decorators

Extending Endpoints with Decorators
Returns an Either[Response, cask.Decor[Any]]. Returning a Left lets you bail out early with a fixed cask.Response, avoiding further processing. Returning a Right provides a map of parameter names and values that will then get passed to the endpoint function in consecutive parameter lists (shown above), as well as an optional cleanup function that is run after the endpoint terminates.

So, your code should be
class AuthenticatedDevKey extends RawDecorator {
  override def wrapFunction(ctx: Request, delegate: Delegate) = {
    // Get the devKey from header
    val devKey = ctx.headers.getOrElse("devKey", "").toString
    // Check if this is a valid devKey
    if(devKey != "" && MicroServiceManager.isExistingDevKey(devKey))
      delegate(Map("devKey" -> devKey))
    else
      Left(cask.Response("Invalid DevKey", statusCode = StatusCodes.UNAUTHORIZED))
    }
}


If I change to that, I get the message Overriding type (Request, Delegate) => Object does not conform to base type (Request, Delegate) => Result[OuterReturned]
The expected return type is Result[OuterReturned], and I am struggling to find out how to conform to this. Thanks for your pointers.
